# Issue with a sorting object array by date

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

**EDIT:** Found the solution of the problem, I thought that Date interpreted this date `("29-04-2020")` as `DD-MM-YYYY`, not `MM-DD-YYYY`. 
For example, I have an object array:

```
let todos: object[] = [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Test',
        'description': 'Just a new task',
        'priority': 1,
        'status': 'during',
        'date': new Date('29-05-2020')
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'test23',
        'description': 'Just a new task23',
        'priority': 3,
        'status': 'done',
        'date': new Date('29-05-2020')
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 2,
        'status': 'in process',
        'date': new Date('29-05-2020')
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 1,
        'status': 'during',
        'date': new Date('29-05-2020')
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 2,
        'status': 'done',
        'date': null
      },
      {
        'id': 6,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 1,
        'status': 'in process',
        'date': new Date('29-05-2020')
      },
]
```

And my task is: sort those objects by date (also I need to skip keys date with property null (that's why I have `operator if` because I have no idea how I can do it another way). So I've created a function:

```
function sortByDate() {
    todos.sort((a, b) => {
        console.log(a, b)
        if (a['date'] == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (b['date'] == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return a['date'].getTime() - b['date'].getTime()
    })
    return todos
}
```

But I've got in sorted objects array on key 'date' (which has a property, **not a null**). Instead of the good properties of dates ( where I had not null ) I've got properties in key "date": "Invalid date" and I have no idea how I can fix it.

Comment: Since they are object you must remove the *single quote '* from the object keys. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following problems in your code:

1. Object keys are string and not identifier. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).
2. Date string is inverted. You must create the date from a string following the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You have to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the invalid dates and then call the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

If you want the array sorted by Date in DESC order use this:

```js
const todos_filtered_sorted_desc = todos_filtered.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
```

otherwise in ASC order use this:

```js
const todos_filtered_sorted_asc = todos_filtered.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
```

Here is the working code (corrected + different dates):

```js
const todos = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Test',
        description: 'Just a new task',
        priority: 1,
        status: 'during',
        date: new Date('2020-05-29')
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'test23',
        description: 'Just a new task23',
        priority: 3,
        status: 'done',
        date: new Date('2019-05-29')
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'test3',
        description: 'Just a new task3',
        priority: 2,
        status: 'in process',
        date: new Date('2021-05-29')
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'test3',
        description: 'Just a new task3',
        priority: 1,
        status: 'during',
        date: new Date('2008-05-29')
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'test3',
        description: 'Just a new task3',
        priority: 2,
        status: 'done',
        date: null
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'test3',
        description: 'Just a new task3',
        priority: 1,
        status: 'in process',
        date: new Date('2000-05-29')
      },
];

console.log(`TODOS[${todos.length}]: ${JSON.stringify(todos)}`);

const todos_filtered = todos.filter(todo => todo !== null && todo !== undefined && todo.date !== null && todo.date !== undefined && todo.date instanceof Date);

console.log(`TODOS FILTERED[${todos_filtered.length}]: ${JSON.stringify(todos_filtered)}`);

const todos_filtered_sorted = todos_filtered.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);

console.log(`TODOS FILTERED SORTED[${todos_filtered_sorted.length}]: ${JSON.stringify(todos_filtered_sorted)}`);
```

You can chain all function into one single operation:

```js
const todos_filtered_sorted = todos
                               .filter(todo => todo !== null && todo !== undefined
                                 && todo.date !== null && todo.date !== undefined
                                 && todo.date instanceof Date)
                               .sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much, but sadly this single operation combined with filter and sort - isn't working :( , and the problem is - I don't know why.
Here is a [link](https://prnt.sc/tdj6mp)

Comment: Instead of getting a normal date I've got Invalid date

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forget that new Date works with MM-DD-YYYY format, not DD-MM-YYYY. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See the problems i found in the answer. To create a valid date you ahve to put YEAR-MONTH-DAY however you have DAY-MONTH-YEAR and the Date constructor says you have an invalid Date.

Comment: Yes, new Date constructor interpreted this 
`("29-04-2020")` as `(MM-DD-YYYY)` not `(DD-MM-YYYY)`

Answer (score 0):

Date format should be `yyyy-MM-dd`

Try with below code

```
let varj = [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Test',
        'description': 'Just a new task',
        'priority': 1,
        'status': 'during',
        'date': new Date('2020-05-29')
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'test23',
        'description': 'Just a new task23',
        'priority': 3,
        'status': 'done',
        'date': new Date('2020-05-29')
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 2,
        'status': 'in process',
        'date': new Date('2020-05-29')
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 1,
        'status': 'during',
        'date': new Date('2020-05-29')
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 2,
        'status': 'done',
        'date': null
      },
      {
        'id': 6,
        'title': 'test3',
        'description': 'Just a new task3',
        'priority': 1,
        'status': 'in process',
        'date': new Date('2020-04-29')
      },
];


function sortByDate(todos) {
    todos = todos.filter(obj => obj.date !== null).sort((a, b) => {
        if(a.date == b.date) return 0;
        
        if (a.date < b.date)
            return -1;
        if (a.date > b.date)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    console.log(todos);
    return todos
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot about it :). Thanks for remembering it.

Comment: @user9779830 you can accept the best answer. either my answer or the other one.